# Cannot Connect to Internet - All applications but Chrome

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome

I didn't know what happened, maybe some programs changed my settings, but I cannot connect to internet using any other browsers but Chrome, it says connection timed out. I am using Win 7

It happened just after I reboot my computer, extra information here: After reboot, Apple Mobile Support Service was chunking up my CPU using half, and my other XLServicePlatform was using the other half. So my computer lagged on 100% of CPU Usage. I need to open Task Manager just after login and stop them to "use" my computer.

Anyway, I tried pinging to google.com and it works, telnet to google.com at 80 works but it takes forever to load and until I type space and returned google's "Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request".

I use AVG, and I heard it might be the firewall's problem, but after disabling the firewall, still nothing happened.

I unchecked all the boxes in the LAN setting and Proxy setting, still nothing happened.

Please help me and inform me so I could provide useful information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you mentioned AVG, you could always try temporarily disabling it. Try that and let us know if that helps. I will try researching on this a little bit.
2. Do you notice any other weird activity on your computer. Perhaps a virus is impairing your ability to connect to the internet. Just because you have anti-virus doesn't mean you cannot get viruses on your computer... Try downloading and scanning with Malwarebytes. [Here](http://filehippo.com/download_malwarebytes_anti_malware/) is a link.

Sidenote: What is your home page on Google Chrome? Usually it is Google... I have noticed a lot lately where a new virus will change your home page to a weird delta site with an advertisement that looks like a Google, but with a weird pop up near the bottom of the screen. You can confirm if it really is Google by looking at the address bar. If it goes to some weird address that says delta in the name, you have a virus. If this is the case, you need to copy off essential documents and re install the operating system...

Comment: yep, funmoods just ruined people's mood. Got that a year ago and got removed. Also, I tried disabling AVG Protection but it didn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: All I am seeing when searching on the internet is that people had viruses. Could you try running Malwarebytes? If you don't want to install software, another option would be to create a Kaspersky live USB drive and boot your computer to that. Make sure you update the software in either case.

Comment: Malwarebytes cannot connect to internet, but I am trying a full scan

Comment: Hmm... The other option to be able to scan your computer with an up-to-date AV is to boot to Kaspersky (live disk). That will not be using your Windows 7 OS at all. It will be able to connect to the internet if it is possible. Have Kaspersky update and then scan. Do other computers on the same local network have the same issue, or is it just this specific computer.

Comment: Also, have you tried re-installing the Apple software?

Comment: I uninstalled it since it bugged me so much

Comment: scanned, but can't fix problem

Comment: sorry, for late comment, but just telling you that Windows magically became functional again?

Comment: It took 15 months to start working again spontaneously? Interesting... I guess we should add that to the troubleshooting steps.

Comment: I guess I forgot about this post :P so yeah